# How do I enable CORS on Azure Storage Blob

Tags: azure, cors, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to customize the UI page on Azure B2C using an Azure storage blob using this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool.md). It needs to be CORS enabled. I have tested it using [test-cors.org](http://test-cors.org) and I know it is not but I do not know how to set it

Ther article uses https://wingtiptoysb2c.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/wingtip/selfasserted.html which I test and returns a 200 but mine does not 
https://bookssorted.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/selfasserted.html

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/set-blob-service-properties#sample-request-and-response) talks about using this `PUT https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties HTTP/1.1`   but how do I run this?

EDIT: I am using Azure Storage Explorer and I have these rules set on the blob but it is still not returning a http 200 from test-cors.org
[image]

EDIT2: this is the url that makes the request to the authentication policy which loads the page that makes the request to load the blob

https://login.microsoftonline.com/bookssorted.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_bookssortedAuthenticationPolicy&client_Id=35f308cd-8914-4035-9f62-cec7600c1727&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbookssorted%2Fsecure%2Fsuccess&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

EDIT3: headers as requested
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include more details about the request? Please tell us the URL from which you're making the request, request method (I'm assuming it is PUT) and all the request headers.

Comment: this is the url that makes the request https://login.microsoftonline.com/bookssorted.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_bookssortedAuthenticationPolicy&client_Id=35f308cd-8914-4035-9f62-cec7600c1727&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbookssorted%2Fsecure%2Fsuccess&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=loginhttps://bookssorted.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/selfasserted.html

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is the URL of the blob that you're trying to fetch via AJAX (and hence CORS). I am interested in knowing the URL from where you make the request to this blob (your application). Is that included in `Allowed Origins`? Also tell us about the request headers as well. Anything that is not defined in the CORS configuration but is included in the request will result in an error.

Comment: @GauravMantri see edit2 above

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details. I am also seeing same behavior. Can you please try something? In your CORS configuration (using Microsoft Azure Explorer), please change `Allowed Origins`, `Allowed Headers` and `Exposed Headers` to `*`. See if this solves the problem in the intermediate.

Comment: that worked...I had tried the headers to be * but not the allowed origins...awesome!! thanks..put it as an answer and I'll mark it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a `cross-origin request` to succeed, the request must match the CORS configuration. This includes the `request origin`, `request headers` & `exposed (response) headers`. Any mismatch there would result in request to fail.

If the origin is known, then that URL must be specified (including protocol & port number if applicable) in the CORS rule. If the origin is not known and you can specify `*` as the origin and all URLs will be able to make such requests.

Same thing goes for request headers and exposed headers. Since different requests to Azure Storage make use of different request headers and return different response headers, it is advisable to set the value for these as `*` in the CORS rule. This will ensure that all request/response headers are accepted.